# Get Data from a callback and save it to a variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, angularjs, callback

Following is my **service** code, which is saving an image -

```
angular.module("app").service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
      uploadFileToUrl: function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(response){
          return response;
        })
        .error(function(){
        });        
      }
    }

}]);
```

In my **Controller** I am having the following code -

```
// Code for Image handling - START
if ($scope.myFile) {
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
    var uploadUrl = "/api/fileUpload";
    console.log("__FILE UPLOAD INFO__CHECK");
    console.log(fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl));

}
// Code for Image handling - END
```

I am expecting to console.log the return data after `console.log("__FILE UPLOAD INFO__CHECK");` but in console its `undefined`

Though I am getting the success response in the console from the AJAX request -

```
{
    "success": true,
    "old_path": "/tmp/ddde0cf3b8a8e4fa83a92b361e814394",
    "new_path": "/MYPROJECT_PATH/uploads/ddde0cf3b8a8e4fa83a92b361e814394.png",
    "save_image_name": "ddde0cf3b8a8e4fa83a92b361e814394.png"
}
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong with the callback here ?

Comment: Any specific reason for down voting or its in your blood ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's async so you should do it with a callback function.

```
angular.module("app").service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
      uploadFileToUrl: function(file, uploadUrl, successCb, errorCb){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(response){
            if(successCb){
                successCb(response);
            }
        })
        .error(function(){
            if(errorCb){
                errorCb();
            }
        });        
      }
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Please add http://pastebin.com/mAf0Y00Q handling code in your answer as well ..as it will help to the future visitors.. Service code - http://pastebin.com/sLKydv1T  Handling code - http://pastebin.com/mAf0Y00Q